# Converting Functional Component code to Class Component code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, react-functional-component, react-class-based-component

I'm new to Functional Components in React and was wondering how I would convert the code below from functional based to class based. I have had a go but I've had troubles around "React.useEffect".

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

(Also a further question, would you say it's better I learn functional components over class based?)

Code

```
import { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import audio from "./250629__kwahmah-02__alarm1.mp3";
import UIfx from "uifx";
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";

function Timer() {
  const [time, setTime] = React.useState(0);
  const [timerOn, setTimeOn] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let interval = null;
    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1); // We wanna increase the time every 10 milliseconds
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
    }

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [timerOn]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {/* <div>{time}</div> */}
        <div>
          <h1>
            {("0" + parseInt(time / 3600)).slice(-2)}:
            {("0" + parseInt((time / 60) % 60)).slice(-2)}:
            {("0" + parseInt(time % 60)).slice(-2)}
          </h1>
        </div>
        <div>
          {!timerOn && time === 0 && (
            <button id="StartTimer" onClick={() => setTimeOn(true)}>
              Start
            </button>
          )}
          {timerOn && (
            <button id="PauseTimer" onClick={() => setTimeOn(false)}>
              Pause
            </button>
          )}
          {!timerOn && time !== 0 && (
            <button id="ResumeTimer" onClick={() => setTimeOn(true)}>
              Resume
            </button>
          )}
          {!timerOn && time > 0 && (
            <button id="ResetTimer" onClick={() => setTime(0)}>
              Reset
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Timer;
```

Comment: Its better to use functional components (hooks) over class components. 
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#should-i-use-hooks-classes-or-a-mix-of-both
As per this, 'In the longer term, we expect Hooks to be the primary way people write React components.'

Answer (score 1):

Side-effects in class components are handled with `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`

So your `useEffect` hook will turn into something like this:

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    let interval = null;
    if (timerOn) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setTime((prevTime) => prevTime + 1); // We wanna increase the time every 10 milliseconds
      }, 1000);
    } else {
       clearInterval(interval);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that any cleanup like `clearInterval(interval)` is now must be made at `componentWillUnmount` lifecycle method

But it is recommended to use functional components.